scp from ubuntu not working
I try to copy a directory to my server.
I have tried:
scp -r /home/user/Dokumenter/ server@10.0.0.21:/home/server/Media
output is:
scp: stat remote: No such file or directory
scp: failed to upload directory /home/user/Dokumenter to /home/server/Media

Tried the same with rsync -rt and it gives the output:
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.3.0]

It's a bit frustrating since my Windows machine can do the scp command without any problems... I did transfer this folder by copying it to an external HDD. plug into Windows machine then scp i over.
I want to do this on my Ubuntu machine not my windows machine :P

This question is similar to: scp command returned `no such file or directory` error. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Its different. I have the path correct and it works from windows. Dont know how I can ask differently to make it more clear for you.

Enabling printing debugging messages by adding the -v (verbose) option to both scp and rsync should be a good starting point so please do that and share the output in your question ... I suspect filesystem related issues so please add types of both source and destination filesystems as well.

What is your Ubuntu version? Since 24.04, scp defaults to using SFTP under the hood - this may cause problems if the remote server doesn't support the SFTP protocol. You can try forcing legacy SCP transfer by adding the -O command line option - see man scp .
